# Please suggest to improve string builder in Kotlin (Android project)

Tags: android, string, kotlin

Please suggest improvements on this code. I want to achieve is: 51.42ºN, 145.20ºW.

Also it would be great if any tool is recommended or online code analysis.

```
        var formattedString = StringBuilder()
        if (latitude.toDouble() < 0) {
            formattedString.append(String.format("%.2f", (latitude.toDouble() * - 1)))
            formattedString.append(0x00B0.toChar())
            formattedString.append("S, ")
        } else {
            formattedString.append(String.format("%.2f", latitude.toDouble()))
            formattedString.append(0x00B0.toChar())
            formattedString.append("N, ")
        }

        if (longitude.toDouble() < 0) {
            formattedString.append(String.format("%.2f", (longitude.toDouble() * - 1)))
            formattedString.append(0x00B0.toChar())
            formattedString.append("W")
        } else {
            formattedString.append(String.format("%.2f", longitude.toDouble()))
            formattedString.append(0x00B0.toChar())
            formattedString.append("E")
        }
        
        return formattedString.toString()
    }
```

Comment: If you have _working_ code that you want reviewed then check out [codereview.se].  Make sure your question meets [their guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise, if your code is _not_ working then please explain what the problem is and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using `kotlin string templates`.

```
import kotlin.math.abs

val latitude = "51.42"
val longitude = "145.20"
val degreeChar = 0x00B0.toChar()
val latitudeDirection = if (latitude.toDouble() < 0) { "S" } else { "N" }
val longitudeDirection = if (longitude.toDouble() < 0) { "W" } else { "E" }
val result = String.format(
    "%.2f$degreeChar$latitudeDirection, %.2f$degreeChar$longitudeDirection",
    abs(latitude.toDouble()), abs(longitude.toDouble())
)
```